# How get unique active element if using grouped list with same values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If I have data like:

```
const data = [
  {
    children: [
      {
         value: "a"
      },
      {
         value: "b"
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    children: [
      {
        value: "c",
      },
      {
        value: "a",
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

and I have list it in react like:

```
{data.map((children) => {
  return (
    <>
      {children.map((item) => {
        <button onClick={() => getItem(item)} className={selectedItem.value === item.value ? "active" : ""}>
          {item.value}
        </button>
      })}
    </>
  )
})}
```

here I'm getting clicked item via getItem method and set it to state and then I'm adding active class to this item if selected item value equal to item.value. But I'm getting to active class on two-item because there is have 2 items with the same values. What to do in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it would be a better idea to get active class based on unique ids instead of non-unique values. you can add id to each element using libraries like [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) or even something like `Math.random()`.

```js
const newData = data.map(item => ({
  children: item.children.map(child => ({
    value: child.value,
    id: Math.random(),  //or uuid(),
  }))
}));
```

then you can render using the newData object:

```
{newData.map((children) => {
  return (
    <>
      {children.map((item) => {
        <button onClick={() => getItem(item)} className={selectedItem.id === item.id ? "active" : ""}>
          {item.value}
        </button>
      })}
    </>
  )
})}
```

Comment: I just think about that while waiting for the answer :) thank you so much.